# How can I keep sound playing on my guitar tuner site the way Fender does on their site?

Tags: reactjs, audio, mobile, audiocontext, howler.js

EDIT: Quickly gonna mention that in mobile, the phone cannot be on vibrate/silent mode or else the sounds won't play for whatever reason.

I created a tune-by-ear guitar tuner using React and Howler.js and so far everything works great on Desktop.

It currently lives here: https://rickyd-dev.github.io/sonus_app/

My source code: [Sonus Repository](https://github.com/RickyD-Dev/sonus_app)

When testing my site on mobile, upon loading the page, the sounds work great. You can tap on the strings and the sounds turn on no problem.

Now, if I were to leave my phone's browser to go into a different app like Twitter for a little bit and then if I come back to my browser with my tuner site still on there, the sounds no longer turn on upon tapping on the strings. I have to do a manual refresh of the page in order for the sounds to play normally again.

I have tried many things like testing the Howler.ctx.state, unloading my sounds and then immediately having them reloaded, and nothing seems to work when it comes to this issue. They all play initially then after leaving and coming back the sounds stop.

I tested the Fender website's guitar tuner ([Fender's online tuner](https://www.fender.com/online-guitar-tuner/electric-guitar-tuning)), and they do not have this issue. I can load up the site, play sounds, leave the browser to browse reddit for a minute, come back and the sounds STILL play no problem.

I tried looking at their source code and I have also tried debugging by connecting my phone to the computer and testing different things from the mobile browser but I'm not having any luck finding what Fender is doing different.

Does anyone know how they're accomplishing this? That is the ONLY issue that I'm having with this and I have not found a way to tap into the problem. I just want my sounds to play even after a user comes back from another app without having to manually refresh.

Comment: I had a quick look but it doesn't seem to play sound at all on iPhone.

Comment: Hi @Jack, I forgot to mention that when using on a phone, the phone has to be on loud as in disabling silent mode from the little notch on the side. Idk why that's happening either tbh. Works no matter if you're on silent mode or loud when plugged in with AirPods, earphones/headphones